# How to Ignore specified characters in SELECT statement Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table, i wanted to remove any characters that present in **Basecode** column data first occurance contains characters **S**,**R**,**A** eg:S2378797 should be 2378797, and  R1165778 should be 1165778 .Rest of the data should be same.
           Name     Description       EID      Basecode

```
      name1      ssdad          1001       S2378797
      name2      gfd            1002       S1164478
      name3      gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778
      name4      ssdad          1004       M0007867
      name5      gfd            1005       N7765111
      name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111
      name5      gfd            1005       N7765111
      name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       A4000011
```

To be like

```
      Name     Description       EID      Basecode        PNO

      name1      ssdad          1001       S2378797     2378797
      name2      gfd            1002       S1164478     1164478
      name3      gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     1165778
      name4      ssdad          1004       M0007867     M0007867
      name5      gfd            1005       N7765111     N7765111
      name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111     W5464111
      name5      gfd            1005       N7765111     N7765111
      name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       A4000011     4000011
```

How do i specify that in a sql query.

Comment: Use Replace and / or IIF or a UDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  table1.field1, 
  IIf((Left(field1,1)='S' Or Left(field1,1)='R' Or Left(field1,1)='A'),Mid(field1, 2, Len(field1)-1) ,field1) AS Expr1
FROM table1;
```

Replace `table1`with your table name, and `field1`with the name of your field.

Comment: Mid is very useful, you do not need to specify length.

Comment: Come to think of it, you might consider LEFT with Instr, to simplify.

Comment: @Remou Good advice, I didn't dig that deep into Access functions.